# Weird alignment of stargazer table

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I am creating a table with stargazer, this is my call:

```
stargazer(mod1,mod2,mod3,mod4,  
          align = T, single.row = T, intercept.top = T, intercept.bottom = F, 
          keep.stat = c("n","adj.rsq","chi2","aic","lr"), omit.stat = "rsq")
```

and this is the resulting table (I cut out all coefficients except intercept)

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-5} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{GPP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ET} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Constant & -4.456^{***}$ $(0.641) & -4.852^{***}$ $(0.871) & -0.983^{***}$ $(0.225) & 0.003$ $(0.285) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{869} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{869} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{869} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{869} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.598} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.673} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.583} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.596} \\ 
$\chi^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{800.747$^{***}$ (df = 9)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{986.216$^{***}$ (df = 14)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{768.444$^{***}$ (df = 9)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{800.340$^{***}$ (df = 13)} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Note that the bottom panel of the table does not match the rest of the table, so the column sep is much too large and cuts off the table on the right side.

[image]

At first I thought it is caused by the unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` calls but removing them by hand didn't fix the problem. Anyone an idea? If I have to correct the table by hand, the package is obsolete for me.

Comment: The usual caveat: you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Comment: One thing which might help a bit is not to add all this extra space between columns with `\extracolsep{5pt}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that changes the overall col sep length but does not fix the initial problem

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree with you, the hard coding makes it really unusuable. Thank you for guiding me to better alternatives

Comment: `gtsummary` is also a great alternative